# Возможна ли взаимозаменяемость стихотворных размеров?

Tags: поэзия

> Спите, полумертвые увядшие цветы,
> Так и не узнавшие расцвета красоты...

В данном отрывке из стихотворения Бальмонта "Придорожные травы" можно проставить сильные доли двумя способами, вследствие чего не будет однозначного ответа на вопрос: какой размер у данного отрывка?

Первый — четырёхстопный пеон 1:
Спи'/те/, по/лу|мёрт/вы/е/ у|вя'д/ши/е/ цве|ты',
Та'к/ и/ не/ уз|на'в/ши/е/ рас|цве'/та/ кра/со|ты'...

Второй — семистопный хорей:
Спи'/те|, по'/лу|мёрт/вы|е'/ у|вя'д/ши|е'/ цве|ты',
Та'к/ и| не'/ уз|на'в/ши|е'/ рас|цве'/та| кра'/со|ты'...

Что думаете на этот счёт?